# Sort lines in file by first field treated as number in shell

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, cut, uniq

I have a file with the format shown below (a number + an IPv4 address). This format was generated by using `uniq -c`. I want to sort the lines after the first number in each of them. I would've gone for something like the `sort` command, but I'm not sure how to use it for sorting after just that number.

```
     20 0.0.0.0
      2 10.0.1.2
      2 10.0.1.4
     97 114.80.166.219
    180 116.6.19.70
   1435 121.11.66.70
      1 12.172.224.140
     34 122.102.64.54
     14 122.165.9.200
    513 122.226.202.12
    650 124.207.117.9
    158 124.51.108.68
    113 125.235.4.130
     24 164.87.166.190
      1 166.129.196.88
    145 173.9.147.165
      3 184.74.167.190
      2 188.131.23.37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to sort on the first octet of the IP address:

```bsh
... | uniq -c | sort -k2,2n
```

gives

```
     20 0.0.0.0
      2 10.0.1.2
      2 10.0.1.4
      1 12.172.224.140
     97 114.80.166.219
    180 116.6.19.70
   1435 121.11.66.70
     34 122.102.64.54
     14 122.165.9.200
    513 122.226.202.12
    650 124.207.117.9
    158 124.51.108.68
    113 125.235.4.130
     24 164.87.166.190
      1 166.129.196.88
    145 173.9.147.165
      3 184.74.167.190
      2 188.131.23.37
```

Note that only sorts on the first octet, as the numeric sorting stops at the first dot (as seen by the unsorted-ness of 124.*)

If you want to sort on each octet, since I don't know if you can tell sort to use whitespace **or** dot as the separator, we'll transform the dots into spaces, sort, then restore the spaces (this process will destroy the leading whitespace, so I'll pipe the output into `column`) -- this relies on GNU sed.

```bsh
... | uniq -c | tr . ' ' |  sort -k2n | sed 's/^ *//; s/ /./2g' | column -t
```

```
20    0.0.0.0
2     10.0.1.2
2     10.0.1.4
1     12.172.224.140
97    114.80.166.219
180   116.6.19.70
1435  121.11.66.70
14    122.165.9.200
34    122.102.64.54
513   122.226.202.12
158   124.51.108.68
650   124.207.117.9
113   125.235.4.130
24    164.87.166.190
1     166.129.196.88
145   173.9.147.165
3     184.74.167.190
2     188.131.23.37
```

Note now the 124.* addresses are numerically sorted.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually wanted to sort after the first field (sorry if my formulation was off), but I maanged to adapt it after what you told me (-k1,1n) :).